# How to make proper animations for a html5 game?

Tags: graphics, flash, image

I am working on a web based MMORPG in html5.

Therefore, I think about using Phaser.io to be the main engine of the game on the client side.

I want the game to be isometric and I am wondering how to make proper sprites/animations/gfx for the game.

I don't want my graphic team to have too much pain.
Would it be possible, for example, to use any kind of "vectorial spritesheet" so that I can zoom in and have a better look at the character.

On the other hand, I don't want the "stuff" (hat, armor, etc) to be too hard to "plug" on the character in all the different orientations.

I thought about using some kind of flash like system (my game is based on the french MMO Dofus which only uses flash for its client side but no web based techno)

But I don't know anything about flash, can I integrate it inside a canvas and does it mux well with raster images like png or jpg?

What alternative could I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the best for your graphic team, then use 3d models. With an orthographic projection and good camera placement (it needs to be rotated 45 degrees around the y axis and 60 on the x axis) you can achieve the same look. In fact, the majority of the isometric games nowadays are actually 3d games with billboards for characters, but you can use models too.

The problem with Flash is that it's losing support. The browsers are on auto update and in the latest versions you already have to allow it. It also doesn't have any support on phones if that's something you're looking into.

You can't integrate Flash with the canvas, they're two different technologies.

As for your speed issue, I don't think you'll get any advantage with Flash anyways, Phaser uses WebGL internally and falls back to the canvas if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are actually scared about the payload of using 3d in a browser/through the network. Wouldn't it be too heavy? And, furthermore, there doesn't seem to be libraries integrating 3d, physics and 3d sound all together. (Or maybe I didn't find it) Would you have any kinda definitive solution?

Comment: @Ninetainedo Small models aren't that big in size, only if you use formats, like .obj. As for the audio, javascript has that covered for you https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/positional_audio/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. What about the drawing/physics part? Is there a good library available for that?

Comment: @Ninetainendo You'll only need a drawing library. You shouldn't do the physics on the client side. There are many engines out there that'll help you draw the graphics, the most basic one is probably Three.js

Comment: Alright I think I'll go 2D then, otherwise this will be way too much effort to get a first version going. Thanks for the feedback, though. Any advices related to 2d?